# Swing Spinner Column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jspinner

I have a class that I use for creating `JSpinner` box based column in a `JTable`. However, I have an issue that when I edit values in new row the old value of the spinner box is shown in the new cell. For example, if I made value in row 1 to be 3, and then move to row 2, the min value of spinner starts at 3, instead of 0. Can somebody suggest a way to modify this behavior?

I was thinking may be I need a separate spinner box for each row and I will have to maintain a map of row number to spinner box, however, I have a feeling that there should be a better solution available.

```
public class SpinnerColumn extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, TableCellRenderer {
    private final JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
    private JTable table;

    public SpinnerColumn(JTable table, int column)
    {
        this.table = table;
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).setCellEditor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue()
    {
        return this.spinner.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
    {
        if (isSelected)
        {
            spinner.setValue(value);
        }
        return spinner;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        return spinner;
    }
}
```

Comment: In getCellEditorValue, call spinner.commit() to commit the value in the spinner to the model. This occurs because the getCellEditorValue method is called before the spinner is notified of the lost of focus

Comment: Also,,make sure you've implemented setValueAt in your TableModel properly

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the setValueAt method in TableModel? Would I need to override that method in my own implementation of DefaultTableModel?

Comment: If you're using a `DefaultTableModel`, then it should be taking care of it, but you didn't provide that information so I just made a point of it